# How to get with TexLive Windows/Linux same extensive verbose level as with Rubber?

Tags: hyperref, texlive, windows, logging, rubber

If I compile the following MWE with Rubber under Linux (`rubber --pdf VerboseDemo.tex`)  I get a nice verbose level including the **HyperRef debug.**

However if I compile with plain pdflatex under windows (`pdflatex.exe VerboseDemo.tex` also under Linux BTW) I get **much less output and not the HyperRef debug**

How can  I get the same extensive verbose level under Windows TexLive as with Rubber on Linux?  How can I enable this on Windows?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[debug=true]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
  \href{tex.stackexchange.com}{tex.stackexchange.com}
\end{document}
```

**Windows Output (`pdflatex.exe VerboseDemo.tex`)**

```
\tex\TexLive2015\bin\win32\pdflatex "D:\tmp\VerboseDemo.tex"  
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(d:/tmp/VerboseDemo.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(d:/tex/TexLive2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(d:/tex/TexLive2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo))
(d:/tex/TexLive2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(d:/tex/TexLive2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(d:/tex/TexLive2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty)
) (d:/tex/TexLive2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(d:/tex/TexLive2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(d:/tex/TexLive2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(d:/tex/TexLive2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(d:/tex/TexLive2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(d:/tex/TexLive2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(d:/tex/TexLive2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(d:/tex/TexLive2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(d:/tex/TexLive2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(./VerboseDemo.aux)
(d:/tex/TexLive2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(d:/tex/TexLive2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty)
) (./VerboseDemo.out) (./VerboseDemo.out) [1{d:/tex/TexLive2015/texmf-v
ar/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./VerboseDemo.aux)

Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `VerboseDemo.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck)                or use package `bookmark'.

 )pdfTeX warning (dest): name{chapter.2} has been referenced but does not exist
, replaced by a fixed one

pdfTeX warning (dest): name{chapter.1} has been referenced but does not exist, 
replaced by a fixed one

<d:/tex/TexLive2015/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb
>
Output written on VerboseDemo.pdf (1 page, 13781 bytes).
Transcript written on VerboseDemo.log.
```

**Rubber Verbose Output (`rubber --pdf VerboseDemo.tex`)**

```
    This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.
    entering extended mode
     restricted \write18 enabled.
     %&-line parsing enabled.
    **\nonstopmode \input{VerboseDemo.tex}
    (./VerboseDemo.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
    Document Class: book 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
    (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo
    File: bk10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
    )
    \c@part=\count79
    \c@chapter=\count80
    \c@section=\count81
    \c@subsection=\count82
    \c@subsubsection=\count83
    \c@paragraph=\count84
    \c@subparagraph=\count85
    \c@figure=\count86
    \c@table=\count87
    \abovecaptionskip=\skip41
    \belowcaptionskip=\skip42
    \bibindent=\dimen102
    )
    (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
    Package: hyperref 2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX

    (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
    Package: hobsub-hyperref 2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)


    (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty
    Package: hobsub-generic 2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
    Package: hobsub 2012/05/28 v1.13 Construct package bundles (HO)
    Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
    Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
    Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
    Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
    Package: ifvtex 2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
    Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
    Package: intcalc 2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
    Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
    Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is detected.
    Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is detected.
    Package: etexcmds 2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
    Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
    (etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
    (etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
    (etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
    Package: kvsetkeys 2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
    Package: kvdefinekeys 2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
    Package: pdftexcmds 2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
    )
    Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
    Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
    Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
    Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
    Package: pdfescape 2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
    Package: bigintcalc 2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
    )
    Package: bitset 2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
    Package: uniquecounter 2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
    )
    Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `hobsub' (already loaded).
    Package: letltxmacro 2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
    Package: hopatch 2012/05/28 v1.2 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
    Package: xcolor-patch 2011/01/30 xcolor patch
    Package: atveryend 2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
    Package atveryend Info: \enddocument detected (standard20110627).
    Package: atbegshi 2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
    Package: refcount 2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
    Package: hycolor 2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
    )
    (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
    Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
    \KV@toks@=\toks14
    )
    (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty
    Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
    )
    (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty
    Package: auxhook 2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
    )
    (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
    Package: kvoptions 2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
    )
    \@linkdim=\dimen103
    \Hy@linkcounter=\count88
    \Hy@pagecounter=\count89

    (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def
    File: pd1enc.def 2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
    )
    \Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count90

    (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg
    File: hyperref.cfg 2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
    )
    Package hyperref Info: Option `debug' set `true' on input line 4319.
    Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4443.
    Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4448.
    Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4451.
    Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4458.
    Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4463.
    Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
    Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4688.
    (..)
    Package hyperref Info: Anchor `Doc-Start' on input line 3.
    Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 5.
    Package hyperref Info: Anchor `page.1' on input line 5.
     [1{/root/.texlive2015/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}
    (..)
```

Comment: That just looks like the difference between the terminal output and the `.log` file to me: have you _checked_ the log you get in the first case?

Comment: Yes that is it! Console Output != Log File

Answer (score 1):

The Log file is more verbose than Console Output. Console Output != Log File. Thanks Jopseph.